# can't install Mongodb properly from terminal ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, express, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongodb on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from this site https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ .

After I running this command :
`sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` I get this :

```
root@walid-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC:/# sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
Need to get 81.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 271 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-shell amd64 4.2.1 [11.9 MB]
Get:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-server amd64 4.2.1 [18.3 MB]
Get:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-mongos amd64 4.2.1 [10.0 MB]
Get:4 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org-tools amd64 4.2.1 [41.5 MB]
Get:5 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2/multiverse amd64 mongodb-org amd64 4.2.1 [3,528 B]
Fetched 81.7 MB in 35min 43s (38.1 kB/s)                                       
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 179789 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_4.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-mongos.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_4.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_4.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.2.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any one can help please !!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There exists an existing package hence the below error "trying to overwrite".

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1

try using  --force-overwrite  to overwrite the package

Command to Run 
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.2.1_amd64.deb

Then run install 
 sudo apt-get install -f mongodb-org

Comment: this worked without reinstalling mongodb, thank you

Comment: This helped me to move forward, thank you!

Answer (score 26):

`sudo apt remove mongo*` and reinstall might help.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me! I had installed it via `apt-get install mongodb`. In the docs it says `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`. You saved my day!

Comment: holy ffs don't use that digital ocean guide. that wasted 2 hours of my time trying to resolve.

Answer (score 12):

The error is caused by your system already having the mongodb package installed, and then trying to install mongodb-org.

Run the following to remove/unistall the existing installed mongo package.

```
sudo apt remove mongodb-org
sudo apt purge mongodb-org
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
```

You might need a `sudo apt autoremove`  too for removing common packages across your system.

Now try to install. You should get it done without any errors for sure this time

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Start mongod

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Check whether mongod is running or not

```
sudo service mongod status
```

Comment: This answer is the closest to what MongoDB CE actually describes, and is technically correct (you have to first remove mongodb-org to then remove the conflicting unsupported mongodb, to then successfulyl reinstall). Careful on which version you are reinstalling! https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/?_ga=2.234564505.606380294.1662993101-1009266786.1662993101#unable-to-install-package-due-to-dpkg-deb--error

Answer (score 0):

check if the mongod package is already present.

```
mongod --version
```

or
check if mongod is already running

```
sudo service mongod status
```

if there is already a mongod package then remove it by using the below command and re install the same.

```
sudo apt remove mongo
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```